# EF 6.1 Targeting multiple database types

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to implement a support for multiple database types in my project (mysql,mssql).
For now my main problem is migrations generation. As i understand i would need to separately generate a migration for each database type?
Is there any standard techniques that can be followed?

Comment: Generally you would want a context per database.  Any reason why you want to be able to 'switch' it?

Comment: Yes that is already done. Actually i don't need to switch them just to add the ability to the users to select what database type they want to use. I am thinking of placing each context in a separate library and that would allow to have independent migrations?